# WordPress Settings API add_settings_error() issue

Tags: php, wordpress

To create plugin custom settings page using wp Settings API wordpress suggests us to use something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'group_name' );
    do_settings_sections( 'group_name' );
    submit_button( 'Save Changes' ); ?>
</form>
```

When I add the settings page errors using the `add_settings_error()` all the things work great. But I have noticed that if `action=""` I'll get 2 copies of the same custom error.

`get_settings_errors()` returns an array with `0` and `2` keys (`1` is missed). In `0` and `2` lays the same custom errors (duplicates).

I am sure it is not an issue of my code due to with `action="options.php"` I have not this issue.

It seems I do not know something. Can somebody explain me?

Answer (score 0):

After the opening form tag, add this function

```
  register_settings( 'myoption-group' );
```

where myoption-group is the same name used in the register_setting function.
You don't have register setting diclear.

refrence link : https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

Comment: it is on the second line of my code: `settings_fields( 'group_name' );`

Comment: sorry about that i wanted to say add register_settings.